# Работа с заполнителями в стоке PHP

Tags: php, mysql

В MySQL в поле храниться шаблон html-страницы:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
style="width:650px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:10px">
<h2><span style="font-size:20px; font-family:Arial; padding 
left:10px;">%ticket_info%</span></h2>
</td>
%loop%
<td style="height:160px; padding-top:10px"> 

<p><span style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; padding-left:10px">
<strong>Сеанс:</strong> %ticket_seance%</span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; padding-left:10px">
<strong>Кинотеатр:&nbsp;</strong></span><span style="font-
size:14px">%theatre%</span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; padding-left:10px"><strong>Зал:&nbsp;</strong></span><span style="font-size:14px">%$hall%</span>
</p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; padding-left:10px"><strong>Дата:</strong>&nbsp; %$date%</span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; padding-left:10px"><strong>Время:</strong>&nbsp; %time%</span></p>
</td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffff"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:35px; vertical-align:top">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="height:35px; vertical-align:top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Как вместо заполнителей подставить значения переменных?

Comment: А какой шаблонизатор используется?

Comment: MySQL-переменных? PHP-переменных? переменных среды? ещё каких-то?

Comment: переменные на php: $ticket_info, $ticket_seance, $theatre и т. д. По названию заполнителей, который приходят из поля в таблице MySQL

Comment: `str_replace(array("%ticket_info%","%ticket_seance%"),array($ticket_info,$ticket_seance),$template);` но это не точно, сейчас народ может шапками закидать